# logstash parsing error (json array )

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to use logstash/elasticsearch.

First, I have tried to put an xml (table) into logstash but, it seemed that xml was unreadable, so I converted it into a json array looking like this:

```
[
  ["bla","blieb"],
  ["things",more"],
                  ]
```

my config looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\Users\mipmip\Downloads\noch.json"
    start_position => "beginning"        
    }
}
filter {
 json {source => message


 }
}
output {
elasticsearch{
hosts => "localhost"
index => "datensatz"       
    }
stdout { }
}
```

But it still doesn't work, all I get are a lot of _jsonparsefailures in elasticsearch :(
 But whyyyy D:

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  ["bla","blieb"],
  ["things",more"],
                  ]
```

This is not a JSON object. 
First, you are missing a double quote near "more". Second, you have an extra comma after the second object. I recommend checking with jsonlint.com if you have a valid JSON.
You should also surround the "message" with double quotes, in the filter part.